# How to create an extension of the Swift struct JoinedSequence?

Tags: swift, generics, swift3

I need to create a wrapper around the function `joined(separator:)` and I think the best way is to create an extension of the `JoinedSequence` struc where the original function is declared.

So i wrote this sample code:

```
extension JoinedSequence {
    func joinWithComma() -> String {
        return joined(separator: ", ")
    }
}
```

unfortunately doesn't work because "*Ambiguous reference to member 'joined()'*".

The `joinWithComma` should work with a sequence of `CustomStringConvertible` and should return a `String`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be what you want:

```
extension Sequence where Iterator.Element == String {
  public func joinWithComma() -> String {
    return joined(separator: ", ")
  }
}

var arr = ["1", "2"]

arr.joinWithComma() // output: "1, 2"
```

---

Looking at the [Array documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/array/1690077-joined) of its `joined(separator: String = default) -> String` **method** , says this:

[image]

And if you tried to use JoinedSequence for this purpose, the new method extension wouldn't get to the Array.

```
extension JoinedSequence where Base.Iterator.Element.Iterator.Element == String {
  public func joinWithComma() -> String {
    return joined(separator: ", ")
  }
}

var arr = ["1", "2"]

arr.joinWithComma() 
// Compiler error: Value of type '[String]' has no member 'joinWithComma'
```

**NOTE:** This is my own observation about this, probably someone more experienced could tell exactly the explanation about this problem.

Comment: could you please explain why the extension is on `Sequence` and not on `JoinedSequence`?

Comment: @IgnazioC It does want you want but on a more general type than JoinedSequence. Therefore why not?